# How to check datas from URL-requests correctly?

Tags: objective-c, arrays, integer, nsdictionary

I catch some data from an URL-request.
Usually it has to be an integer value which is stored in the database.
So i got the following code:

```
if ([[sourceDict objectForKey:@"fields"] objectForKey:@"id"]) {
    if ([[[sourceDict objectForKey:@"fields"] objectForKey:@"id"] isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
        if ([[sourceDict objectForKey:@"fields"] objectForKey:@"id"] > 0) {
            self.id = [[[[sourceDict objectForKey:@"fields"] objectForKey:@"id"] objectAtIndex:0] intValue];
        }
    } else {
        self.id = [[[sourceDict objectForKey:@"fields"] objectForKey:@"id"] intValue];
    }
}
```

The problem right now is that someone put some other values, e.g. also Strings than integer into that database field from the URL-request.

So the App crashes now because objectForKey:@"id" is not an integer any more?

How to check it now? I guess it is not a good way to check if it is a String value, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is some quite good practice to do type-checking on input data from json or alike.

Use `[someObject isKindOfClass:[AClass class]]`

e.g. `[[sourceDict objectForKey:@"fields"] objectForKey:@"id"] isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]`

So you are doing that already and check if the object is of type `NSArray` (or any of its subclasses). You can do just the same with `NSNumber` and `[[[sourceDict objectForKey:@"fields"] objectForKey:@"id"] objectAtIndex:0]` or `[[[sourceDict objectForKey:@"fields"] objectForKey:@"id"] intValue]`